# How to persist a list of anonymous implementations of an interface in Java?

Tags: java, database, jpa, functional-programming, software-design

I have a Java class that stores a reference to a list of implementations of a given interface, and I want to persist objects of this class, if possible using my existing Spring JPA/Hibernate framework.

For example, let's say I'm developing a game where stats of a player, like his hit points, strength or other attributes can be altered dynamically by a bunch of effects that change the base value for these properties each in their own way. For this, I designed the following generic class that represents a property that can be altered by a number of modifiers:

```
public class ModifiableProperty<T> {

    private T baseValue;

    // How can I persist this attribute?
    private List<Modifier<T>> modifiers = new ArrayList();

    public ModifiableProperty(T baseValue) {...}

    public T getValue() {
        T value = baseValue;
        for (Modifier<T> modifier : modifiers) {
            value = modifier.apply(value);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public void addModifier(Modifier<T> mod) {...}
    public void removeModifier(Modifier<T> mod) {...}
}
```

It stores a base value for this property as well as a series of modifiers (applied when calculating the total value), which are represented by implementations of the following (functional) interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Modifier<T> {
    T getModifiedValue (T value);
}
```

I can add anonymous implementations of `Modifier` to the modifiable property dynamically, for example as lambda expressions.

I am very new to JPA and, honestly, to database usage in general. How would an experienced developer go about persisting objects of the `ModifiableProperty` class? I am currently using Spring-based JPA with a PostgreSQL database, but I can also switch if necessary.

I tried to annotate the `ModifiableProperty` class with `@Entity` and the `modifiers` attribute with `@OneToMany`, so far so good. However, there are a number of things that seemingly make this non-trivial: generics, use of polymorphism, and especially the fact I can't statically specify all possible implementations of `Modifier`. To make polymorphism work, I have often come across the `@AnyMetaDef` and `@MetaValue` annotations, however, it seems like they always require explicitly specifying the possible implementing classes. This is not an option for me, since I want to make use of lambdas and anonymous classes rather than explicit classes which I have to add to this annotation everytime I create a new implementation.

Another option might be to store it as a raw byte array. However, this doesn't feel like an elegant solution and may present consistency and compatibilits issues when things change.

I feel like my usecase is rather uncommon or avoided in practice. This makes me think that maybe I am thinking and designing the wrong way and something like that isn't what JPA and relational databases should be used for? I am open to all advice.

So I guess my question is: How would an experienced engineer go about architecture, design, and persistency in such a usecase?